# EF Core Power Tools does not keep identity column name

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-power-tools

I have <s>.NET Core 3.1</s> .NET Standard 2.0 class library with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.8.` I am using VS 2019 with EF Core Power Tools `2.4.217`

All my SQL table names are pluralize and have identity column with the following naming convention `{TableName}ID`. So for example `Documents` table has identity column `DocumentID`

When I use reverse engineering to generate entities, the power tool generate property name as `DocumentId` instead of `DocumentID`

Same issue happens with foreign key column.

How do tell power tool not to change `ID` to `Id`?

**UPDATE 1**
Note that I have another .NET Core 2.* application with different DB. And I am using same version of power tools and it generated `ID` as `ID` as expected.  But having issues with .NET Core 3

Comment: Please create an issue in the EF Core Power Tools repo

Comment: created an issue in repo